# H2 tries to create database in invalid location

Tags: h2

when I try to create a database in H2 in the web console with the following url

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/data/vervikMonitor
```

I get the following error:

```
IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
C:\Program Files\H2\bin\data\vervikMonitor.lock.db (No access)"; 
"C:/Program Files/H2/bin/data/vervikMonitor.lock.db" [90031-162] 90031/90031 (Help)
```

I have a norwegian version of Windows, so the path to my program folder is `C:/Programfiler/` - why does H2 try to access the english style `c:/Program Files/`, where is that reference stored?

Comment: Where and how did you start H2 in server mode?

Comment: The installer (NSIS) most likely installed H2 in the directory `C:/Program Files/` and this is where you started the H2 server I guess. Or possibly H2 isn't installed in this directory, but the current working directory of the H2 server is `C:/Program Files/` when that program was started.

Comment: the strange thing is that "c:/Program Files" doesnt even exist on my machine, I have it in norwegain "C:/Programfiler". I downloaded in from Firfox and just ran the executable from there Firefox downloaded it, which in this case was the regular download folder in my user dir.

Comment: Well, what file did you download and run? The installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try absolute paths (note the `//`):

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost//data/vervikMonitor
```

Of course you must make sure that `C:\data\vervikMonitor` is writable. Or you can use a different directory :)